# Regular expression validation: Not validating all email types

Tags: validation, email-validation

I have written the regular expression validation for email below:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_\+-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\+-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\.([a-zA-Z]{2,})$
```

But According to the MSDN link for valid and invalid emails: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/testing123/archive/2009/02/05/email-address-test-cases.aspx

Valid emails:

```
email@[123.123.123.123]
"email"@domain.com
email@123.123.123.123
```

Invalid emails:

```
email@-domain.com 
email@domain.web
```

But my current regular expression doesn't validate above 5 email types.

Can anyone help? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the comments on php.net regex functions, there a lots of examples about this. Personally I only check if the @ and domain extension are valid because the new generation postmasters seem to accept a lot of crap in email addresses. have seen things like `you're@domain.com` which sadly enough are valid according to RFC standards.

Comment: But Client is asking to validate it anyhow!